# Access image field URL in a custom block

Tags: 8, blocks, media

I need to have an easily exposed to user background image in an aera (header).
So i made a custom block with an image field and i want to use this picture in a classical `<div style="background...`.
So I need the URL of the file and of course not the rendered file.

Since two days i'm searching a way to do that without success. And twig debug activated do not help.
I'v tried the `image_url_formatter` module (doesn't work with twig debug active)
I've found this:

```
{{ file_url(content.field_header_background['#items'].entity.uri.getValue()) }}
```

But it only giving me the root folder (by de file_url function i think) the part:

```
content.field_header_background['#items'].entity.uri.getValue()
```

is empty.

I have heard about preprocess function (on block, filed ?) but i don't know how to do it.

Is anyone can help me ?

Comment: getValue() is not working, it returns an array. Try `.value` or the code in the duplicate question.

Comment: Finally the problem was at the data source.
When i've created the block i gave a default source image and didn't add another one.

So when i was rendering simply the field in twig 
{{content.field_header_background }}
The default image was rendered. But when i tried to acces to url source by
{{ file_url(content.field_header_background['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}
i was having only the root path and nothing behind so i was thinking this doesn't working.

But as soon i'v added an picture in the field it worked. The default image url seems to use a different way.